# Add the sum of this column under the special column and write into file via python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I export statistics from the Oracle server to an Excel file using python, and I need to write the total amount later in the file, under special columns

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
Filename='stat.xlsx'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user='',password='',dsn='')
data=pd.read_sql("""select s.name,count(1) as lines,sum(s.or_num) as packs....""",con)
con.close()
data.head()
data.to_excel(Filename,index=False)

print('done')
```

[image: This is what I want to do.]

Comment: Please be more clear. What you want to do? sum what with what? What do you mean by "special column"?

Comment: Suppose column D has the name Line, or packs, and it is necessary to sum up all the values in this column and write below the total